# Node.js application doesnt start up on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am trying to understand why is my heroku application not working anymore. It worked before, but suddenly it started showing an error in its logs:

2021-11-20T17:43:09.447233+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-11-20T17:43:09.592799+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-11-20T17:55:53.598178+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-11-20T17:55:55.576714+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2021-11-20T17:55:56.282257+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-11-20T17:55:56.614501+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

And it wont start the application at all. Why is it not working?

I also get this error occasionally:

2021-11-20T20:25:09.785827+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785842+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785842+00:00 app[Worker.1]:           ^^^
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785842+00:00 app[Worker.1]:
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785843+00:00 app[Worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785843+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785843+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785843+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785844+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785844+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785844+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785845+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785845+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object. (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785845+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-11-20T20:25:09.785845+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/l

Edit: I know sending the code is important but I really have no idea what code is relevant to the error and theres a a lot of code in this project.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your program. Try running your program locally, and look for errors. If it works fine locally, then try checking the Heroku configuration.

Comment: The program does work locally. What should I look for in the Heroku configuration?

Comment: @GFTK Do you have a Procfile set correctly for your worker?

Comment: @Viriato i believe i do. 


Worker: node main.js